# Magento 2 Auto Redirect To Product Details Page If Category Have Only One Product

Tags: magento2, category, product-view

Magento 2 Auto Redirect To Product Details Page If Category Have Only One Product

only one product in a category, just go to product detail page when clicking that category menu

i'm use `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);` in Magento 1.

this working in  Magento 1 but not working in  Magento 2

How to change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a redirect in your file for Magento 2, you need to use `Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory` in your file.

```
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
```

Create a `protected` variable to use in your class.

```
protected $_resultFactory;
```

Now create an object for this class in your `__construct` function,

```
public function __construct(YOUR_OTHER_OBJECTS, ResultFactory $resultFactory)
{
    .. YOUR CODE ..
    $this->_resultFactory = $resultFactory; // Create object for ResultFactory
}
```

Now you can use this object to redirect to your URL like,

```
$redirect = $this->_resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$redirect->setUrl($url); // set your URL variable
return $redirect;
```

Comment: ok. I try this code